# API Express - I get [object Object] when I show the request in the console

Tags: node.js, xml, express

I try to show the request that I send with the Postman in the console but I get the following message in the console: Request==>[object Object]

I would like to show the message in an xml or in a string by console as it is sent from the Postman.
I attach image of the shipment with the Postman:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
function test1(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) : string {

    console.log("Request==>" + req.body);

    let respuestaJSON : string = "";      
   
    return respuestaJSON;
}
```

Many Thanks for your help.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `JSON.stringify(req.body)`, it will convert your object into a string to print.

EDIT:

Try with `console.log("Request==>", req.body)`, your object should be visible in the line after the string.

Comment: This does not work.
I get the following: Request==>{}
This is my code now:
function test1(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) : string {

    let rq = JSON.stringify(req.body);

    console.log("Request==>" + rq);

    let respuestaJSON : string = "";
       
    return respuestaJSON;
}

Comment: console.log(req.body) should work just fine, or maybe the request received is not what you except

Comment: This is a XML (see Postman please)

Comment: @Javi take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41552432/express-api-json-and-xml-post-request

Comment: This is solved now. Many thanks Ivan.